# Add multiple style sheet globally

Tags: css, angular11

How to add multiple style sheet globally in Angular 11 ?

I am trying to add multiple style sheet globally in Angular 11. I added Style sheets in `angular.json` file like below.

```
"test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/assets/css/bootstrap.css",
              "src/assets/css/owl.carousel.css",
              "src/assets/css/owl.theme.css",
              "src/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css",
              "src/assets/css/animate.css",
              "src/assets/css/magnific-popup.css",
              "src/assets/css/settings.css",
              "src/assets/css/slick.css",
              "src/assets/css/icons.css",
              "src/assets/css/preset.css",
              "src/assets/css/theme.css",
              "src/assets/css/responsive.css",
              "src/assets/css/presets/color1.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
```

But it is not working.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you use `scss` in your project you can import css files in the `styles.scss` like so:

`@import ./src/styles/some.css`

The imported files will be compiled together by `ng build` so there is no need to provide them in the `assets` folder.

Comment: Thanks @David B. Where should I place CSS files ? How to add multiple style sheet globally ?

Comment: Just add them to a custom styles folder /src/styles/, and then import them in the styles.scss they will be treated globally.